# How to specify color for each vertex if i have duplicates?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, opengl

I have a plane with 4 points. I wrote a subdivision algorithm. I can subdivide my plane and get all needed vertices for subdivided plane. But what Is the problem? I have some duplicated vertices in my array but i want to specify different color for each of them. I draw with VBO and EBO, color will sended with vertexAttribPointer. So, can you give me some recommendations to solve this problem?
My Plane

```
using Vector3D = QVector3D;
std::array<Vector3D, 4> plane
            {   // +Z SIDE
                   Vector3D(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
                   Vector3D( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
                   Vector3D( 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f),
                   Vector3D(-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f)
            };
```

My subdivision algorithm

```
void subdivisionSurface(std::vector<Vector3D>& vertices, std::array<Vector3D, 4> plane, unsigned int iterations = 1)
{
    if (iterations == 0)
    {
            return;
    }
    else
    {

        Vector3D e1 = plane[1] - plane[0];
        Vector3D e2 = plane[2] - plane[3];
        Vector3D e3 = plane[3] - plane[0];
        Vector3D e4 = plane[2] - plane[1];

        Vector3D p1 = (e1 * 0.5) + plane[0];
        Vector3D p2 = (e2 * 0.5) + plane[3];
        Vector3D p3 = (e3 * 0.5) + plane[0];
        Vector3D p4 = (e4 * 0.5) + plane[1];
        Vector3D e5 = p2 - p1;
        Vector3D p5 = (e5 * 0.5) + p1;

        if(!(std::find(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), p1) != vertices.end()))
            vertices.push_back(p1);
        if(!(std::find(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), p2) != vertices.end()))
            vertices.push_back(p2);
        if(!(std::find(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), p3) != vertices.end()))
            vertices.push_back(p3);
        if(!(std::find(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), p4) != vertices.end()))
            vertices.push_back(p4);
        if(!(std::find(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), p5) != vertices.end()))
            vertices.push_back(p5);

        std::vector< std::array<Vector3D, 4>> subPlanes
        {
                    { plane[0], p1, p5, p3 },
                    { p1, plane[1], p4, p5 },
                    { p5, p4, plane[2], p2 },
                    { p3, p5, p2, plane[3] }
        };

        if (iterations == 1)
           return;
        else
        {
            for(auto& splane : subPlanes)
                  subdivisionSurface(vertices, splane, iterations - 1);
            return;
        }

    }


}
```

Honestly, it is not my algorithm, i just a little bit refactored what i founded under another question on StackOverflow. But i clearly understand what it does.

You can see that i didn't add duplicated vertices now, then for this data i will generate IBO and draw my subdivided plane with different color for each vertex. I see that check for each new vertex isn't efficient way. Do you know how to fix this? How to fix my algorithm or how to specify the same color for repeated vertices. I belive that QVector3D make exact comparison of float number.

Comment: If you duplicate a vertex, technically you simply add a new vertex at the same position as the old one. This new vertex can have any color you'd like. The number of elements in the  colors vector must anyway match the number of elements in the vertices vector (after the duplication).

Comment: @wohlstad This approach is not comfortable , i want to make an interface for setting color for each vertex. For example user want to set color for vertex (0, -0.25, -0.5) but i have several vertices with the same value, i need to find every vertex with this value and specify color for it.

Comment: @АндрейПетров: The clean approach would be to separate the logical datastructure (the one where you have only one vertex with multiple normals) from the render datastructure (the one where you have multiple distinct vertices at the same location).

Comment: @BDL is it good to keep all repeated vertices and draw them?I will have a 6 planes each of them consists of about 25'000 vertices if calculate without duplicates. I afraid to imagine how much useless information i will keep.

User will not send color for each vertex manually, he will have a file with coordinate of vertex and it color(Just imagine, it is possible use case). He will write something like this:
```
pair_values(Pos, Color) = file.read()
for each value in pair_values:
      set_color_for_vertex(value.pos, value.color)
```

Comment: At first glance, this looks like it’s O(n^2). Is it? Is that a problem. You may want to use a hash table to keep track of what’s in the vector.